# Как настроить миксины в SASS?

Tags: sass

Как настроить миксины в SASS? Подключаю файл с миксинами в общий SCSS файл, но миксин, указанный в файле с миксинами, не работает, компилятор выдает ошибку:

> Error: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.
>  
>           on line 41 of css/base.scss, in `border-radius'
>  
>           from line 41 of css/base.scss
>  
>           from line 2 of style.scss

```
'@'mixin border-radius($radius) { -webkit-border-radius: $radius; -moz-border-radius: $radius; -ms-border-radius: $radius; border-radius: $radius; } .mix { background: grey; width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; border: 5px solid black; '@'include border-radius(10px); } '@'
```

Comment: Напишите, как вы подключаете. Нам нужен минимальный работающий пример, демонстрирующий ошибку, чтобы разобраться.

Comment: Это запись в Миксинах:
 '@'mixin border-radius($radius) {
-webkit-border-radius: $radius;
-moz-border-radius: $radius;
-ms-border-radius: $radius;
border-radius: $radius;
}

.mix {
 background: grey;
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 5px solid black;
 '@'include border-radius(10px);
}

'@' - взята специально, чтобы написать комментарий можно было так

Comment: @SvArt713: такую информацию стоит добавлять прямо в вопрос — тем более, там есть форматирование кода. Отредактировал; добавьте пожалуйста переносы строк туда, чтобы код нормально читался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я понял свою ошибку, изначально в главном файле-компиляторе, важно, чтобы файл миксинов был выше чем файл стилей!